# PHP Error - Invalid request (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Tags: php

This is my encounter when I tried to start PHP and made an access to my PHP site.

In this case, I entered in my browser `http://localhost:8888`

And my desired page didn't render. After checking what's in the console, here's what I've got:

```
C:\web\laravel>php -S localhost:8888 -t C:\web\laravel

PHP 5.6.11 Development Server started at Wed Aug 05 21:01:42 2015
Listening on http://localhost:8888
Document root is C:\web\laravel
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Wed Aug 05 21:02:07 2015] ::1:64507 Invalid request (An existing connection was
 forcibly closed by the remote host.
)
[Wed Aug 05 21:02:07 2015] ::1:64508 Invalid request (An existing connection was
 forcibly closed by the remote host.
)
[Wed Aug 05 21:02:07 2015] ::1:64509 Invalid request (An existing connection was
 forcibly closed by the remote host.
)
[Wed Aug 05 21:02:08 2015] ::1:64514 Invalid request (An existing connection was
 forcibly closed by the remote host.
)
[Wed Aug 05 21:02:08 2015] ::1:64513 Invalid request (An existing connection was
 forcibly closed by the remote host.
)
[Wed Aug 05 21:02:08 2015] ::1:64515 Invalid request (An existing connection was
 forcibly closed by the remote host.
)
```

I tried to look on the internet, and here in StackOverflow, but it doesn't seem like anyone has solved it yet.

I also came to check through https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=An+existing+connection+was+forcibly+closed+by+the+remote+host&x=0&y=0 and I didn't find any relevant answer.

Here's my PHP version:

```
C:\>php --version
PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 20:55:40)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I'm also running **Windows 8.1 64-bit**

Has anyone experienced this issue? How did you managed to solve it?

Comment: Did you try other port?

Try:

```php -S localhost:8080 -t C:\web\laravel```

Comment: Yes it works with another port. But what do you think causes this issue? I checked on ``netstat`` and the said port is not in use.